# CSS Drop Down list not working in chrome

Tags: css

i use this css code in IE7 and it works great without any problems.
Now in IE11 and chrome the drop down doesn't work i see the main menu and all sub menus together.
need an assistance in that to understand what can be done to fix it.
Thanks.

```html
<div id='cssmenu'> 
  <ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='url'><span>text</span></a></li> 
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>text</span></a></li> 
    <ul> 
      <li><a href='url'><span>text</span></a></li> 
      <li><a href='url'><span>text</span></a></li> 
    </ul>
```

```css
body {
    background: #4096EE url(images2/img1.jpg) repeat-x;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    color: #333333;
}

h1 {
}

h2, h3 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

h4, h5, h6 {
}

p, ol, ul, dl, blockquote {
}

a {
    color: #1B4978;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Header */

#header {
    width: 600px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#header h1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 42px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
}

#header h2 {
    float: right;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding-top: 28px;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* Menu */

#menu {
    width: 600px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline;
}

#menu a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #EEEEEE;
}

#menu a:hover {
    background: #CCCCCC;
}

/* Content */

#content {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#colOne {
    float: right;
    width: 360px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#colTwo {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#colTwo ul {
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    list-style-position: inside;
}

#content h1 {
    background-color: #B2D4F7;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    color: #173E68;
}

#content h2 {
    background-color: #B2D4F7;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #173E68;
}

#content h3 {
    color: #2F73B8;
}
/* Footer */

#footer {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
}

#footer p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #999999;
}

#footer a {
    color: #666666;
}

#footer a:hover {
    color: #333333;
}

#cssmenu{
    border:none;
    border:0px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
    font: 67.5% 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Bitstream Vera Sans', 'Trebuchet Unicode MS', 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width:600px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
#cssmenu ul{
    background:#333333;
    height:35px;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
#cssmenu li{
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    }
#cssmenu li a{
    background:#333333 url('seperator.gif') bottom right no-repeat;
    color:#cccccc;
    display:block;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:35px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 25px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
#cssmenu li a:hover, #cssmenu ul li:hover a{
    background: #2580a2 url('hover.gif') bottom center no-repeat;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
#cssmenu li ul{
    background:#333333;
    display:none;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width:225px;
    z-index:200;
    /*top:1em;
    /*left:0;*/
    }
#cssmenu li:hover ul{
    display:block;

    }
#cssmenu li li {
    background:url('sub_sep.gif') bottom left no-repeat;
    display:block;
    float:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:225px;
    }
#cssmenu li:hover li a{
    background:none;

    }
#cssmenu li ul a{
    display:block;
    height:35px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-style:normal;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 15px;
    text-align:left;
    }
#cssmenu li ul a:hover, #cssmenu li ul li:hover a{
    background:#2580a2 url('hover_sub.gif') center left no-repeat;
    border:0px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
#cssmenu p{
    clear:left;
    }
```

Comment: Please include some sample HTML that demonstrates the problem; the question will likely be closed fairly quickly otherwise.

Comment: <div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='url'><span>text</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>text</span></a></li>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='url'><span>text</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='url'><span>text</span></a></li>
          
      </ul>

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that HTML works as expected anywhere, but then IE7 is a large pile of bugs.

You have a `<ul>` as a child of another `<ul>`, which isn't valid HTML. `<ul>` can only contain `<li>` elements. That sub-menu list should be the *child* of the `<li>` above it:

```
<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>text</span></a> 
  <ul> 
    <li><a href='url'><span>text</span></a></li> 
    <li><a href='url'><span>text</span></a></li> 
  </ul>
</li>
```

```css
body {
    background: #4096EE url(images2/img1.jpg) repeat-x;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    color: #333333;
}

h1 {
}

h2, h3 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

h4, h5, h6 {
}

p, ol, ul, dl, blockquote {
}

a {
    color: #1B4978;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Header */

#header {
    width: 600px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#header h1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 42px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
}

#header h2 {
    float: right;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding-top: 28px;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* Menu */

#menu {
    width: 600px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline;
}

#menu a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #EEEEEE;
}

#menu a:hover {
    background: #CCCCCC;
}

/* Content */

#content {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#colOne {
    float: right;
    width: 360px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#colTwo {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#colTwo ul {
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    list-style-position: inside;
}

#content h1 {
    background-color: #B2D4F7;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    color: #173E68;
}

#content h2 {
    background-color: #B2D4F7;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #173E68;
}

#content h3 {
    color: #2F73B8;
}
/* Footer */

#footer {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
}

#footer p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #999999;
}

#footer a {
    color: #666666;
}

#footer a:hover {
    color: #333333;
}

#cssmenu{
    border:none;
    border:0px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
    font: 67.5% 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Bitstream Vera Sans', 'Trebuchet Unicode MS', 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width:600px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
#cssmenu ul{
    background:#333333;
    height:35px;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
#cssmenu li{
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    }
#cssmenu li a{
    background:#333333 url('seperator.gif') bottom right no-repeat;
    color:#cccccc;
    display:block;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:35px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 25px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
#cssmenu li a:hover, #cssmenu ul li:hover a{
    background: #2580a2 url('hover.gif') bottom center no-repeat;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
#cssmenu li ul{
    background:#333333;
    display:none;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width:225px;
    z-index:200;
    /*top:1em;
    /*left:0;*/
    }
#cssmenu li:hover ul{
    display:block;

    }
#cssmenu li li {
    background:url('sub_sep.gif') bottom left no-repeat;
    display:block;
    float:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:225px;
    }
#cssmenu li:hover li a{
    background:none;

    }
#cssmenu li ul a{
    display:block;
    height:35px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-style:normal;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 15px;
    text-align:left;
    }
#cssmenu li ul a:hover, #cssmenu li ul li:hover a{
    background:#2580a2 url('hover_sub.gif') center left no-repeat;
    border:0px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
#cssmenu p{
    clear:left;
    }
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'> 
  <ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='url'><span>text</span></a></li> 
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>text</span></a> 
      <ul> 
        <li><a href='url'><span>text</span></a></li> 
        <li><a href='url'><span>text</span></a></li> 
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```